# Unexpected router redirection

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm trying to redirect an Admin to `http://localhost:8080/dash` if isAdmin is `true` but it keeps redirecting the user to home. If I input `http://localhost:8080/dash` in my address bar it redirects to `http://localhost:8080/dash?activeTab=dashboard`.

If i do this:

```js
 if (isAdmin) {
      this.$router.push({ name: "rex" });
    } else {
      this.$router.push({ name: "home" });
    }
```

it redirects the Admin to rex, but if I do this:

```
if (isAdmin) {
      this.$router.push({ name: "dash" });
    } else {
      this.$router.push({ name: "home" });
    }
```

it redirects the Admin to home instead of `http://localhost:8080/dash` which will automatically return `http://localhost:8080/dash?activeTab=dashboard`. Please how do I go about this?

Comment: You need to show how you've defined your routes.  It's impossible to know how your router is expected to behave without this information.

Answer (score 0):

i had conflicting route in my dash component